# Commenting out lines of python code as part of a function

Tags: python, function, comments

Let's say that I have written a function in Python, but I would like to be able to choose to comment out (i.e. make noncompilable) any number/combination of lines of its code as part of the function. Is there an efficient way to do that? So hopefully something more efficient then writing some sort of "if/else" for every line of code, as I would have to do it 200 times. So an input of Function(vars,[1,4,5,66,86]) means that lines 1,4,5,66 and 86 do not compile.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about meta programming?

Comment: I guess so, but I don't know anything about it :-)

Comment: It looks like you want to modify interpreted code on the fly. Maybe module `ast` could help you with this. But that is an ambitious project for a Python novice.

Comment: Why are you expecting the result of commenting out some arbitrary set of lines, to be compilable code that does anything meaningful? What if you happen to comment out, for example, the `def` statement introducing a function, but not any of the function body? Also, what *problem do you hope to solve* by doing this?

Comment: By cnstruction, a lot of the code consists of lines that are independent of each other- if one line is commented out, the rest will still work together.

Comment: I think one-line if-statements is the way to go. Self-modifying code is probably a bad idea

Comment: why not use `if/else` with some argument send to function. It is standard method. Commenting code is very strange idea. Or maybe you should create two functions - with and without some code.

Comment: if your function has 86 lines then maybe you put too much code in one function. Maybe you should split it in smaller funtions and then use `if/else` to run only some of this functions.

Comment: If I use if/else, I will have to do it 200 times.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your function is as follows

```
def printing():
    print("first")
    print("second")
    print("third")
```

and it is saved in a file "modify_me.py". Then you can do the following

```
def modify_it(filename, skips):
    newfunc = ""
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f):
            if i not in skips:
                newfunc += line
    return newfunc

newfunc = modify_it("modify_me.py", [1,3]) #skip lines 1 and 3
exec(newfunc)
printing() #will only print "second"
```

This is not as simple as it may seem, since you will have to handle namespaces if you want all of this to happen within a function, but it is definitely a possible way to go.